# Using a wildcard in the command line as sys.argv[2]

Tags: python, bash

**The problem**

I'm trying to write a script which converts a file type into another using SeqIO, ideally on the command-line I'd write:

```
python3 converter.py *.ab1 *.fas
```

But this doesn't work. However, when I use the following, it works fine:

```
python3 converter.py *.ab1 workingexample.fas
```

**My current code**

This my code at the moment.

```
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO

file = sys.argv[1]
outputfile = sys.argv[2]

with open(file, "rb") as input_handle:
    with open(outputfile, "w") as output_handle:
        sequences = SeqIO.parse(input_handle, "abi")
        count = SeqIO.write(sequences, output_handle, "fasta")

print("Converted %i records" % count)
```

**Desired output:**

A fix for

```
python3 converter.py *.ab1 *.fas
```

Which means I can run this on multiple files in the same directory with the same extension, and then output a file with the same name but the new converted extension.

(I'm not sure whether to tag this as a bash question or a python one, so I have tagged it as both, please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: So you want to convert `workingexample.ab1` into `workingexample.fas`? Is there only ever one file that matches `*.ab1`?

Comment: No, there will be multiple, but there is only one in my test directory which is why the working example works, but wouldn't achieve what I want it to.

Comment: Your problem is not only in the python code, but on the call. The code gets solved with glob, but more important is that when you use `*.ab1` or `"*.ab1"` you are asking the shell to expand that into actual filenames. You need to use `'*.ab1'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
import sys
import glob
import os
from Bio import SeqIO

file = sys.argv[1]
output_extension = sys.argv[2]

for f in glob.glob(file):
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f)
    outputfile = f.replace(file_extension, output_extension)

    with open(f, "rb") as input_handle:
        with open(outputfile, "w") as output_handle:
            sequences = SeqIO.parse(input_handle, "abi")
            count = SeqIO.write(sequences, output_handle, "fasta")

    print("Converted %i records" % count)
```

You can call it like this:

```
python converter.py '*.ab1' .fas
```

Comment: It seems strange to me to prevent globbing in the shell and then use `glob.glob` in your own code.

Comment: I'm not using `get_output_filename`. Looks like the code on the other answer.

Comment: Apologies, I was editing a script in the wrong directory, it works great

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think the issue is that `*.ab1` matches a file (at least one), whereas `*.fas` doesn't match anything. This means that your program gets called like:

```
python3 converter.py first.ab1 second.ab1 third.ab1 *.fas
```

and `*.fas` is passed, unexpanded. Clearly from this example, you cannot rely on `*.fas` being the second argument - it is the *last* argument.

I would argue that the shell is helping you here by expanding the glob, and that there's no need to prevent it from doing its work by e.g. enclosing your arguments in quotes.

I would suggest that you call your script like:

```
python3 converter.py *.ab1 fas
```

Then change the code to:

```
import sys
import os.path
from Bio import SeqIO

files = sys.argv[1:-1]
output_ext = sys.argv[-1]

def get_output_filename(input_filename, output_ext):
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(input_filename)
    return "{}.{}".format(root, output_ext)

for in_file in files:
    out_file = get_output_filename(in_file, output_ext)
    with open(in_file, "rb") as input_handle, open(out_file, "w") as output_handle:
        sequences = SeqIO.parse(input_handle, "abi")
        count = SeqIO.write(sequences, output_handle, "fasta")
    print("Converted %i records" % count)
```

Since you're converting to "fasta" format no matter what the last argument is, then I guess you could just rename the script to `convert_abi_to_fasta.py` and drop the last argument.

Comment: I get this error, but it might not be the fault of the code... `File "A01_150218_PV_RF-HL001b_PRKC1Fwd.ab1", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xff' in file A01_150218_PV_RF-HL001b_PRKC1Fwd.ab1 on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details `

Comment: I'm not sure about that error, but I just saw your comment on the other answer and fixed the variable name in my code.